# Match string between two other different strings

Tags: javascript, regex

Another regex question:

I'd like to capture text that exists between two different marker strings. The thing is, the marker strings have a few options. For example:

I'm very hungry **for a sandwich** and tomorrow I'll go to the store - capturing between "I'm very hungry" and "and"

I'm very tired **so I'll go to sleep**. - capturing between "I'm very tired" and ".".

I'm coding in Javascript, and I thought:

```
/string one(.*?)string two|\.|string three|string four/gi
```

But that doesn't seem to work. It just grabs between `string one` and `string two` ignoring `string three` and `string four`.

What am I doing wrong with the regex?

Comment: `/string one(.*?)(string two|\.|string three|string four)/gi`?

Comment: How do you know how many words to skip and what to skip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you need to group strings because `|` has low precedence

```
/string one(.*?)(?:string two|\.|string three|string four)/gi
```

Edit: adding parentheses changes precedence because the expression in parentheses is evaluated before the rest of the expression. In addition, here we use non-capturing groups because we use the `(?:` syntax.

Comment: Hi Akonsu. That works thanks. I was wondering if you could add to your answer about the low precedence. Why does adding the parentheses and the ?: change precedence? I'm not familiar with regex, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. Very helpful.